# How is parent/child inheritance accomplished for modules in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, can parent/child inheritance be accomplished for modules?

For instance if I have data for a protocol header, I can create a class  *header*, and variations that inherit from it, such as *long_header* and *short_header*. The parent class can have a method like *set_parity*, and variations can optionally be defined for long or short headers as needed, like *long_header.set_parity*

Modules to process these headers, like "long_header_processor" would then use the long_header.set_parity method.

Is this how it's done?

Is there an alternative way to obtain this inheritance, to somehow have a "long_header_processor" module inherit from a parent "header_processor" module?

Answer (score 0):

No, in SystemVerilog, modules are a much more 'hardwary' construct, there's no concept of inheritance for modules. They can be parameterizable, but that's it. Classes and modules are very different concepts in SV - modules are typically used in design, and classes in verification.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also address the "Is this how it's done?" part of the question?

Comment: It's simply not done: in design, you try to make your modules as configurable as possible (in terms of I/O ports that can change the internal behaviour depending on their value). But once a module is designed, that's it. If you need a module with slightly different functionality that is not covered by configurability or parametrization, you will have to implement a completely new module. Think of SV classes world as C++, while the 'module world' is more like C.

Comment: Yes, I figured. I am very familiar with Verilog and C/C++ but new to SV, so it's a bit disappointing that with all the hoopla, there's no such thing. Is there any concern with the proposed approach? That is "to implement a completely new module" (as you write), like "long_header_processor", but using inherited classes inside it to somehow leverage the clarity from OOP?

Comment: Oh I see your profile now, so yeah, if you are fluent in verilog, what you get in systemverilog in terms of design is good: you get structs/interfaces, better arrays, the 'logic' type, which solves a lot of pains versus wire/reg, and nice process blocks such as always_ff, always_comb... but yeah, in terms of 'software like' stuff (generic programming, inheritance etc)... none of that is actually synthesizable, it's only meant for verification code, not for design :-(